# how can i make a for loop in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, reactjs, web

this code works whenever I change the number on index I know I need to use a loop but I don't know how I tried using `for (int index = 0; index > i.length ; index++)`{ but it wasn't working I'm very sorry for asking I just really don't know how

```
constructor() {

    super();
      this.state = { jsonReturnedValue: [] ,
      name: '',
      address: ''
      }

    }

renderItem(d, i) {
  let index = 0;
    debugger
    index++;
    let name = d.Employee_Name;
    let address = d.Address;
      //  for (int index = 0 ; index > i.length ; index++){

    return <tr key={i} >

  <td> {d.Employee_ID} </td>
        <td>{d.Employee_Name}</td>
        <td>{d.Address }</td> 
        <td><center><button className ="btn btn-info" onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i) }   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateEmployee">Edit</button></center></td>
  <td><center><button className ="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></center></td>

<div className="modal fade" id="UpdateEmployee" role="dialog">
         <div className="modal-dialog">
           <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 className="modal-title">Update Employee</h4>
              </div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="modal-body">
                <table> 
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td> <input type="text"value={this.state.jsonReturnedValue[index].Employee_Name} /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td><input type="text" value={this.state.jsonReturnedValue[index].Address} />  </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <botton className="btn btn-info"> Update Employee</botton>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
 </tr>
}
```

this is where i call the table ...

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/getemployeedetails')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()})
  .then((json) => {
    this.setState({jsonReturnedValue : json});
  });
}


render() {


  let {jsonReturnedValue} = this.state;
    return(

        <div>
    <div className="container">
        <h1> Listof Employees </h1>
      <button className ='btn btn-warning right ' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddEmployee"> Add an Employee</button>
        <table className= "table table-bordered">

            <tbody>
             <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Address</th>
                  <th>Update</th>
                  <th>Delete</th>
             </tr>
                {jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) => this.renderItem(d,i))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
  </div>
```

I have a problem it only reads the first row item, i dont know why it does that.. how can i use foreach loop for this... or any kind of code so it will work because it doesn't read any other row besides the first one im so confused because I haven't done reactjs before

PS: the data came from an api from asp.net... [you can check the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjOt4.png)

Comment: Could you provide the structure/value of `jsonReturnedValue`? Also, could you provide the implementation of `renderItem`?

Comment: your for condition for (int index = 0; index > i.length ; index++) is invalid, you probably want index < i.length instead